# Azure Synapse Analytics NoAuthenticationInformation

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am using the following tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace

When I get to the step of opening https://test.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall.parquet, I get the following error:

{
"error": {
"code": "NoAuthenticationInformation",
"message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.\nRequestId:05e79b63-b01f-009e-2449-6ef31c000000\nTime:2024-03-04T15:33:46.8866412Z"
}
}

My user account, found in Microsoft Entra ID, has read/write/execute access to the NYCTripSmall.parquet file and is listed as a Synapse Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, make sure the user having `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role on the Data Lake Storage Gen2.

[image]